# Phonegap jQuery Mobile Background CSS issue - 1px at the bottom of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am having an issue with my background image. In the attached image you can see a 1px line at the bottom of the screen where the background has repeated. I want the background to fill the entire screen.

My CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bg-large.png) top center !important;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: auto 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: none;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

It does not seem to matter what resolution I view it on, the line is still there. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
[image: Background]

Comment: You sure it isn't the image itself? Or did you put in the margin:0px; padding:0px; and border:0px;

Comment: try overriding `.ui-page` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pv8Sn/

Comment: Most likely coming in from .ui-page what omar said above.

Comment: Thanks Omar, overriding .ui-page solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in jQuery Mobile, `body`'s height is set to `99.9%`, that's why your image doesn't fill the page 100%. Override `.ui-page` class to fix this problem.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Pv8Sn/)**